# Grails rest plugin SSLexception strange comparing of domain names (domainname/ip-address)

Tags: rest, grails, ssl, httpclient, ssl-certificate

I am getting this strange error. Well the error sure has been seen before. However note the (at least for me) unique part of this is that it is complaining about:

```
<testapi.multisafepay.com/213.189.1.163>
```

Which is different then all similar issue I encounter that show that it is comparing just an ip-address with the domain name of the certificate.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <testapi.multisafepay.com/213.189.1.163> != <testapi.multisafepay.com> OR <www.testapi.multisafepay.com> OR <testapi.multisafepay.com>
```

The context is a grails 1.3.7 application with the "rest" plugin version 0.6.1

What options do I have either with or without disabling ssl domain verification?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to connect via the IP address or the host name? Where does `testapi.multisafepay.com/213.189.1.163` come from? (Any chance of seeing which class throws this exception and/or a bit more of the stack trace?)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the code that impacts what you are doing. It is from rest plug 0.7, SimpleHTTPBuilderSSLHelper class.

```
if (sslSocketFactory) {
    // Set the hostname verifier for the trusted certificates...
    if (config?.https?.cert?.hostnameVerifier) {
      switch (config.https.cert.hostnameVerifier.toUpperCase()) {
        case CERT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER_STRICT:
          sslSocketFactory.hostnameVerifier = SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
          break;
        case CERT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER_ALLOW_ALL:
          sslSocketFactory.hostnameVerifier = SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
          break;
        case CERT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER_BROWSER_COMPATIBLE:
          sslSocketFactory.hostnameVerifier = SSLSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
          break;
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "The https.cert.hostnameVerifier doesn't match any of the following ${CERT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIERS.join(', ')}")

      }
    }
```

These are the various hostname verification options that you have.